# Why can a regression tree not identify a perfect predictor?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, boosting

If a dataset contains a perfect predictor a linear regression is able to identify this variable. Why is it that a tree model cannot do the same?

In the R code below, the dataframe **df** contains an independent variable **IndPerfect** that is identical to the dependent variable **Target**. For the illustration only the last row is used for out of sample forecasting. A linear regression gives a perfect forecast and the parameters of the other parameters are set to (almost) zero:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Ind1 = rnorm(100),Ind2 = rnorm(100),Ind3 = rnorm(100),Target = rnorm(100)) 
df$IndPerfect<- df$Target #generate perfect independent variable

testindex <- 100
indizes_train <- 1:90
indizes_validation <-  91:99

#Lin. Regression
model <- lm(Target~.,data = df[indizes_train,])
df$Target[testindex] - predict(model,newdata = df[testindex,])  #Perfect Forecasts by the lin. Regression
#-3.330669e-16
```

This result is not surprising. However, I was not able to generate a perfect forecast by using a tree method such as in R's extraTrees or xgboost. The following code uses xgboost including the validation sample of 10 rows from the code above:

```
library(xgboost)
#Gradient Booster
name <- c("Ind1","Ind2","Ind3","IndPerfect")

set.seed(1)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(df[indizes_train,name]), label=(df[indizes_train,"Target"]))  
dval <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(df[indizes_validation,name]), label=(df[indizes_validation,"Target"])) 
watchlist <- list( train = dtrain,eval = dval)

param <- list(  objective           = "reg:linear", 
    eta                 = .01,
    subsample           = 1,
    colsample_bytree    =1,
    eval_metric         = "rmse"
)

xgbmodel <- xgb.train(   params              = param, 
        data                = dtrain, 
        nrounds             = 1000, 
        verbose             = 1, 
        early.stopping.round     = 50,
        print_every_n = 5,
        watchlist           = watchlist,
        maximize            = FALSE,
        nthread = 2)

dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(df[testindex,name]))  
df$Target[testindex] -predict(xgbmodel, dtest, ntreelimit = xgbmodel$bestInd)
# -0.02821238
```

It does not matter what parameters I choose - no tree model (xgb or et) ever gives a perfect forecast. Is there a theoretical reason for a tree model to not be able to make perfect forecasts?

Comment: Good question. I reckon its because trees are splitting data by variables and then fit regression to each node. So inherently are losing some information along the way

Comment: @JanSila whilst some regression trees do what you say, xgboost doesn't fit a regression in the leaf nodes. Each leaf is assigned a weight which is returned as the prediction. For regression with squared error the leaf weight is the mean of the y vaues associated with the leaf.

Answer (score 1):

For linear model, you could try gblinear in xgboost.
Why it is linear model, you can check the model summary:

[image: summary(model)]

Gblinear example:

```
library(xgboost)
#Gradient Booster
name <- c("Ind1","Ind2","Ind3","IndPerfect")

set.seed(1)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(df[indizes_train,name]), label=    (df[indizes_train,"Target"]))  
dval <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(df[indizes_validation,name]), label=(df[indizes_validation,"Target"])) 
watchlist <- list( train = dtrain,eval = dval)

param <- list(  objective           = "reg:linear", 
eta                 = .01,
subsample           = 1,
colsample_bytree    =1,
eval_metric         = "rmse"
)

xgbmodel <- xgb.train(   params              = param, 
    data                = dtrain, 
    nrounds             = 1000, 
    verbose             = 1, 
    early.stopping.round     = 50,
    print_every_n = 5,
    watchlist           = watchlist,
    maximize            = FALSE,
    nthread = 2)

dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(df[testindex,name]))  
df$Target[testindex] -predict(xgbmodel, dtest, ntreelimit = xgbmodel$bestInd)

#  1.536799e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each tree grown by xgboost splits y into leaf nodes conditional on X. The prediction (or leaf weight) is the value which minimises the loss function for the split y's - so for example if the loss function is squared error, the leaf weight is the mean of the y's.

So say you have 1 tree of depth 1 (i.e. a single split on 1 feature). All this model can return is two discrete values, the mean of the y's for either the left or right leaf. So even a simple linear response takes a large number of splits / trees and will still never produce a smooth function.

There are regression trees which apply a linear regression to the X,y in each leaf node but `modern' implementations like xgboost, catboost, lightgbm etc don't do this.

Edit: also because of this, trees cannot extrapolate outside the data they were trained with